# How to auto-generate URLs in Craft?

Tags: url

How to auto-generate URLs in Craft? For example when we upload images on Tumblr, an URL to the post is created:

http://twotimeselliott.tumblr.com/post/95032257420

And an URL for the image is created:

http://31.media.tumblr.com/2142197f5273865770be44723c2a5df0/tumblr_nagyr9INCE1r6ky2bo1_500.jpg

How can we do that in Craft?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m not sure if those Tumblr URLs are just an incrementing ID (so each new post is +1 greater than the last one), or if it’s a randomly-generated string of numbers.

If you just want yours to be the entry ID, all you’d have to do is go into your section’s settings, and set the following:

- **Do entries in this section have their own URLs?** [check]
- **Entry URL Format:** `post/{id}`

If you want it to be random, that’s a little more difficult. You would need to create a custom text field that stores the random number, attach it to your section, and start entering random numbers into it when creating new entries (or you could write a custom [field type](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/field-types) that handles this for you). Then your **Entry URL Format** would get set to `post/{customFieldHandle}` instead of `post/{id}`.

As for the image URL, if you have an Assets field that’s responsible for storing the entry’s main image, you can set it to restrict uploads to a single directory, and give it a subfolder based on the entry’s ID/random number custom field handle. (See http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/assets-fields#restricting-uploads-to-a-single-folder)

Answer (score 0):

Entries have the **url** attribute, which you can access like so:

```
<a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
```

[See example in the docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries)

If you upload an image through Assets, you can get the url for the image by doing something like this:

```
<img src="{{ entry.imageHandle.first().getUrl() }}" alt="" />
```

Note that the getUrl takes an optional transform name, if you have added any [transforms](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/image-transforms).

See more in the [docs on craft.assets tag](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.assets).

Comment: Hi Fred, sorry I meant auto URLs like "95032257420" instead of the URL title...

Comment: I wrote a plugin that allows you to generate strings like that: https://github.com/sjelfull/Craft-Randomm